# View .crc code un-jumbled

Tags: linux, software-development, code-review, reverse-engineering, firmware

Hi I have a firmware file which gets loaded onto video devices.
The file is updated every year but there is a bug in this specific version.
So I would like to take a look at the code myself.

The video device runs off linux.

I am using windows 10 64x.
[image]
The file has a .crc extension (not sure if it's a cyclic redundancy check?) I can open the file in [inno](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and can view the contents however, the file is jumbled up with nonsense characters.
I would like to know what software I could use to view this file...

ALSO the manufacturer of the video device said something about using [source insight](https://www.sourceinsight.com/) but the code was still jumbled. It's difficult communicating with them because they speak another language.

Any suggestions and/or an explanation of this file will be greatly appreciated.

[LINK](https://mega.nz/#!cHpHQQzD!_BLuNaiH7RrdZQ5ucqbfHvJ-pBpp5tRRSCUlnZUbnD4) to files 10.9MB

[LINK](https://mega.nz/#!FSwhmIoA!QGuafi2_XhcNoukFszsueWWRYTuv60flhH1siV-7chY) to video of .crc file in inno jumbled 87.6MB

Answer (score 1):

The file is likely [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code). The "nonsense characters" you're seeing are bytes of code being misinterpreted as bytes of text in some 8-bit encoding, perhaps Windows-1252. If you identify the instruction-set architecture of the devices on which the file runs, you can probably disassemble it. However, disassembly produces [assembly language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), not the original source code. In general, source code can't be recovered from machine code. You'd need to get a copy of the source code from the author. Debugging a dissembled program is possible, but incredibly difficult and labor-intensive unless the program is very simple.